# form and file upload to two different controllers

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, post, file-upload

I have a form that I want to submit with one submit button.

However my action to upload a file is a different controller then the database posts.  it looks like this...

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/upholstery_product/add/">
<h3>Add a Product</h3>
Frame: <input type="text" name="productname" /><br>

Parent Category:
<select name="category">
    <?php
    foreach($cats AS $cat){
        $sel = ($curCat->category_id == $cat->category_id) ? 'selected' : '';

        echo "<option value='".$cat->category_id."' ".$sel.">" . $cat->category_name . "</option>\n";
    }
    ?>
</select><br />

Family: <input type="text" name="family" /><br>

Width: <input type="text" name="width" size="6" /><br>

Height: <input type="text" name="height" size="6" /><br>

Depth: <input type="text" name="depth" size="6" /><br>

Seat Width: <input type="text" name="seat_width" size="6" /><br>

Seat Height: <input type="text" name="seat_height" size="6" /><br>

Seat Depth: <input type="text" name="seat_depth" size="6" /><br>

Arm Height: <input type ="text" name="arm_height" size="6" /><br>

Features: <textarea cols="40" rows="20" name="features"></textarea><br>

<form method="post" action="/upload/product_image_upload">
Image File: <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/><br>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/upload/product_image_upload">
Thumbnail File: <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"/><br>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/upload/pdf_upload">
PDF File: <input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf"/><br>
</form>

Status: <select name="status">
        <option value="active">Active</option>
        <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select> <br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product" /><br>
</form>
```

is there a way to post the file actions to one controller and the submit to my other controller with a single submit button? right now the code doesnt work.

Comment: You should add the MVC tag :)

Comment: done. haha.  I dont get it though. these are html files not xhtml, I thought nested forms were acceptable

Comment: lol, seem we both did it at the same time :)

Comment: I dont think it matters if its HTML or XHTML. Nested forms cannot be done like this.

Comment: To allow your form to handle multiple actions you can add a hidden text field :)

Comment: Are you using a framework? Can you extend and override your controller and include a call to the other controller which handles the upload?

Comment: You cannot use the word "height" with multiple fields as name, what you're doing will only pass the last "height" field, anyway regarding your question unless you want to call 2 controllers when submitting you can accomplish this through a hidden field & some JS

Comment: ah i didnt see that. thats an easy fix. But I wouldnt mind calling two controllers.

Comment: You are aloud to run mulitidimensional posts in codeigniter and it should work fine , you should look at like a Ajax request maybe , Also look into the codeigniter HMVC pattern

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is, strictly speaking, not possible: You have two separate forms on one page, andf you want to submit both simultanously.

The main problem here is this: The result of a submitted form is a new page. Different actions = different pages. Which one do you want to display?

Workaround: Submit both the file and the data to the same script; if the handlers *need* to be separate, make the first handler post the data to the second handler "behind the scenes".